# Can I access my websites MS SQL 2008 database from another application

Tags: iphone, android, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

Basically I am creating a database driven website in Web Developer 2008. The database is stored in the App_Data folder of my website project. Could I have an iPhone, Blackberry, Symbian, Windows Phone, webOS or Android app access the database via an HTTP (or some other type of) request?

I would like to know if this is possible before I move too far in the programming.

Comment: Why not expose functionality as web services (or mobile-friendly web pages)?

Comment: I could do it like that. Basically I just want to know if the database will be accessible by programs, websites, apps etc. other then the website it is built into.

When the time comes for that step I'll work on a more structured approach to complete it but for now I want to know if my data will be physically bound to only this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible, although perhaps the most secure method would be to abstract the connection to the database through a WCF service or even a conventional web service.

That way the database connection string remains on the server, and the web service will allow pass-through connectivity, so to speak.  This is just a security layer to prevent someone from grabbing the database connection string and accessing your database directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... this has Web Services written all over it.  Heck, once you figure that out, you might find yourself going back and scrapping most of the code you wrote for your app, having it use the Web Services you just wrote.

XML and XSLT - send them "Facebook Friend Requests" - join their MySpace page - follow them on Twitter - take them out for cocktails - get them liquored up and laid on the hottest silicon you can get your hands on.  They'll take care of you for years to come, I promise.